# Symbolize is not Working Properly

Tags: custom-notation

I am trying to introduce a special superscript notation in mathematica but it does not work

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Needs["Notation`"]
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SuperscriptBox["W", "(c)"]]]
W^(c) = 1

(* Set::write: Tag Power in W^c is Protected. >> *)
(* 1 *)
```

However, it works in the following case

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Needs["Notation`"]
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SuperscriptBox["W", "_"]]]
W^(c) = 1

(* 1 *)
```

I don't understand that why it is not working in the first case! and I really need to just set that special notation not every superscript.

It should be mentioned that if one directly uses the `Symbolize` from notation palette there won't be any problem at all but the thing is that why the equivalent 2D command is not working properly.

Comment: Are you literally using `Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SuperscriptBox["W", "_"]]]` or the template generated by the palette? (I know if you cut and paste you get the `ParsedBoxWrapper`) I get no problems using the palette template but get the same problem using your 2D code

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch: I am using the 2D code. So it seems to be a bug or we are missing something!

Comment: use the palette. that is what it was designed for

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch: I got it from your previous comment but why the equivalent 2D code is not working!

Comment: You should check the box structure of `W^(c)` by using `Cell | Show Expression` and make sure your pattern is consistent.

Comment: @CarlWoll: I had the same idea but couldn't find what is the low level pattern for my notation. Thanks for the attention but I couldn't find how to use those commands you mentioned! Can you kindly write an answer in this regard. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you've typed the following in a cell:

<kbd>W</kbd>  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> <kbd>(</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>)</kbd>

Then, go to the menu, and select Cell | Show Expression (or use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> on OSX).

You will find that the box structure is:

```
SuperscriptBox["W", RowBox[{"(", "c", ")"}]]
```

not

```
SuperscriptBox["W", "(c)"]
```

So, try using the above box structure instead.